# when adding api and publishing getting the error:"Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed wso2 1.10.0 on private server, when adding api and publishing getting the error:

```
Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed
```

what is the issue here? anything else need to be installed?

please reply any suggestions on it at the earliest

Comment: Have you done any customizations on API Manager?

Comment: can you provide the full error log

Comment: No, i have not done any customization. Downloaded the new release and unzipped it. in the UI, when i click on save&publish button above mentioned error message will display

Comment: Here is the error i can see in the command prompt:

Comment: Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution
 failed for action : Publish
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCyc
le.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:440)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEvent
ingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:319)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspe
ct(HandlerManager.java:2792)

Comment: at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.i
nvokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(Embe
ddedRegistry.java:2550)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspec
t(CacheBackedRegistry.java:469)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserR
egistry.java:1951)

Comment: at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactI
mpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:817)
        ... 67 more
[2016-03-31 11:57:13,856] DEBUG - ThreadingView Thread state summary for Passthr
oughHttpServerWorker threads - Blocked: 0.0%, Unblocked: 100.0%